# Calculating upper culmination of the Moon

Tags: time-series, entity, astronomy

I’m completely confused by the new astronomical data system in Mathematica. For every day in some interval, I want to calculate
`{azimuth, altitude}` of the Moon in moment of its upper culmination.

I’ve already realized that I can’t get this data directly.
But we can calculate the culmination as the exact midpoint between `RiseTime` and `SetTime`, and further we can use `MoonPosition`.

But how can I get `RiseTime` and `SetTime` for the Moon? From `PlanetaryMoon` data?
And how can I get correct time of upper culmination, since it’s not just a half sum of `RiseTime` and `SetTime`?

**UPD, PS**
Thank you for great answers! Using it, I got a graph of the Moon’s positions at transition moment of a year.

[image]

I'm interesting is it show really [Moon's librations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration), or just inaccuracy of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica provides "upper culmination" as the `TransitTime` property of `PlanetaryMoon` data. With the transit dates, we can get azimuth and altitude from `MoonPosition`.

The `TransitTime` property has two qualifiers for date and location. For example,  let's use `EntityValue` and `TransitTime` qualifiers to find the Moon's transit time for October 2023 at Lowell Observatory, Flagstaff, Arizona, United States.

```
EntityValue[EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "TransitTime"], "Qualifiers"]
(* {"Date", "Location"} *)
```

Let's get the rise, transit, and set times for `location` and `dates` in October 2023. First, use the rise times to find the following transit times, and then use the transit times to find the following set times. This gives us a sequence of rise time, transit time and set time for each date.

```
(*Lowell Observatory, Flagstaff, Arizona, United States*)
location = Entity["AstronomicalObservatory", "LowellFlagstaff"];
dates = DateRange[DateObject[{2023, 10, 1}], DateObject[{2023, 10, 30}]];

(*find next rise time for each date*)
r=EntityValue[Entity["PlanetaryMoon",  "Moon"],
 EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon",
  "RiseTime", {"Date" -> #, "Location" -> location}]] &/@ dates;

(*find transit time following each rise time*)
t=EntityValue[Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"],
 EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon",
  "TransitTime", {"Date" -> #, "Location" -> location}]] &/@ r;

(*find set time following each transit time*)
s=EntityValue[Entity["PlanetaryMoon",  "Moon"],
 EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon",
  "SetTime", {"Date" -> #, "Location" -> location}]] &/@ t;
```

Demonstate that the transit times are not the midpoint of rise time and set times. The times are accurate to the nearest minute.

```
r + (s - r)/2 - t
(* {5 min, 4 min, 2 min, 0 min, 1 min, -2 min, -3 min, -4 min, -5 min, -5 min, -5 min, -5 min, -4 min, -4 min, -4 min, -4 min, -3 min, -3 min, -1 min, 0 min, 2 min, 3 min, 4 min, 5 min, 5 min, 5 min, 5 min, 5 min, 4 min, 3 min} *)
```

Use `MoonPosition` to get azimuths and altitudes for each transit time. The azimuths are close to 180 degrees but not equal because of the limited accuracy of the times. Use `DateListPlot` to graph the Moon's altitude at transit.

```
{azimuths,altitudes} = MoonPosition[location,t]["PathComponents"];
Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation}[azimuths]]
(* {180.04°, 0.195364°} *)

DateListPlot[altitudes,
  PlotLabel -> Style["Moon Altitude at Transit", Bold, Black]]
```

[image: Moon altitude at transit]

Display a table of rise, transit, and set times.

```
fmt = {"Day", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Year", " ", "Time"};
TableForm[Transpose[{DateString[#, fmt[[;;-2]]] &/@ dates,
  DateString[#, fmt] &/@ r,
  DateString[#, fmt] &/@ t,
  DateString[#, fmt] &/@ s}],
TableHeadings -> {None, {"Date", "Next Rise", "Next Transit", "Next Set"}}]
```

Comment: Great answer, but why data comes so slow? I remember in WM 9-10 AstronomicalData was received in a second, and now `RiseTime` for 30 days takes 5-7 sec, and `TransitTime` - over 15 sec

Answer (score 5):

Just make it a maximization problem.

For example, set some given date and location:

```
pos = GeoPosition@
  Entity["City", {"Chicago", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}]
t0 = DateObject[{2023, 10, 1, 0, 0}, "Minute", "Gregorian", -4.`]
```

Now create an objective function that returns the true altitude at each time of the day from 0 to 24 hrs:

```
tUnit = Quantity[1, "hour"]
obj[i_?NumericQ] := 
 QuantityMagnitude@
  Last@MoonPosition[pos, t0 + i tUnit, 
    AltitudeMethod -> "TrueAltitude"]
```

and maximize the altitude:

```
maxTime = NArgMax[{obj[x], 0 < x < 24}, x]
maxPos = 
 MoonPosition[pos, t0 + maxTime* tUnit, 
  AltitudeMethod -> "TrueAltitude"]

(*3.32927*)
(* {Quantity[181.565, "AngularDegrees"], 
 Quantity[61.1416, "AngularDegrees"]}*)
```

The same can be done for lower culmination as well:

````
minTime = NArgMin[{obj[x], 0 < x < 24}, x]
minPos = 
 MoonPosition[pos, t0 + minTime* tUnit, 
  AltitudeMethod -> "TrueAltitude"]
(*15.6206*)
(*{Quantity[358.755, "AngularDegrees"], 
 Quantity[-32.5243, "AngularDegrees"]}*)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `RiseTime` for a specific location and date:

```
PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", 
  EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "RiseTime", 
  {"Location" -> GeoPosition[{30, -95}], 
   "Date" -> DateObject[{2023, 12, 1}]}] ]
```

[image]

For example, here are `RiseTime` and `SetTime` for five months:

```
risetimes = 
  PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "RiseTime", 
  {"Location" -> GeoPosition[{30, -95}], 
   "Date" -> #}] & /@ 
    DateRange[DateObject[{2023, 11, 1}], DateObject[{2024, 3, 31}]]];

settimes = 
  PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "SetTime", 
  {"Location" -> GeoPosition[{30, -95}], 
   "Date" -> #}] & /@ 
    DateRange[DateObject[{2023, 11, 1}], DateObject[{2024, 3, 31}]]];
```

To convert them to minutes of the day

```
risetimemins = #[[4]] 60 + #[[5]] & /@ DateList /@ risetimes
settimemins = #[[4]] 60 + #[[5]] & /@ DateList /@ settimes

ListPlot[{risetimemins, settimemins}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

### Updated

Azimuth:

```
azimuths = 
  PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", 
   EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "Azimuth", 
   {"Location" -> GeoPosition[{30, -95}], 
    "Date" -> #}] & /@ 
    DateRange[DateObject[{2023, 11, 1}], DateObject[{2024, 3, 31}]]];
```

This is gives results that look like

```
azimuths[[1 ;; 3]]
  (* {Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{67, 10, 42.}], 
  MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "Arcminutes", "Arcseconds"}]], 
 Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{60, 30, 57.}], 
  MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "Arcminutes", "Arcseconds"}]], 
 Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{54, 22, 28.}], 
  MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "Arcminutes", "Arcseconds"}]]} *)
```

```
ListPlot[Normal@azimuths, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Transit altitude (apologies - I'm not sure if this is the same as the upper culmination):

```
alt = PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", 
   EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", 
      "AltitudeTransit", {"Location" -> GeoPosition[{30, -95}], 
       "Date" -> #}] & /@ 
    DateRange[DateObject[{2023, 11, 1}], DateObject[{2024, 3, 31}]]];

(* example results *)
alt[[1 ;; 3]]
  (* {Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{87, 43.55}], 
  MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "Arcminutes"}]], 
 Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{88, 14.54}], 
  MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "Arcminutes"}]], 
 Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{87, 8.70}], 
  MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "Arcminutes"}]]} *)

ListPlot[Normal@alt, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: How about upper culmination?

Comment: @user64494 Updated the answer.